# How to display a full page splash screen in Windows 8

Tags: javascript, windows, iframe, microsoft-metro, splash-screen

Does anyone know if Windows 8 App allows full page splash screens?  I look at the app.manifest and it requires a 600 x 300 picture with a colored background.

I also looked at scaling but that seems to be for screen that have higher resolution.  So even if I supply the 1116 x 540 image, it will still display the same relative to the standard image in a higher resolution display.

The only way I can think of right now is to somehow dismissed the splash screen and add my own  inside the iframe. (my app is loaded through an iframe) Or does anyone know another way?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the way you have described is the correct way to work around this. Consider however that a user probably just wants to get into your application as quickly as possible.

This [code sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Splash-screen-sample-89c1dc78) will probably help you a lot.